# Alternating sequence, and Absolute Convergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$$

The alternating sequence I thought of applying theorem six from chapter 8 of *James Stewart Essential Calculus Early Transcendentals Second Edition* which states the following:

> ### Theorem 6
>
> If $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \vert a_n \vert = 0$, $ \ \therefore \ $ $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}  a_n = 0$.

I took the absolute value of the sequence to get rid of the negative one. Leading me to the following:

> $$\vert a_n \vert = \frac{n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$$
>   $$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+\sqrt{n}}=1$$

Is there a corollary to the theorem that states that it is divergent, as Symbolab stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_{2n} \to -1$ and $a_{2n+1} \to 1$ so $\lim a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: How did you learn how to plug in the $2n$, and $2n+1$?

Comment: The moment you see $(-1)^{n}$  you should consider odd and even values of $n$ separately. @EnlightenedFunky

Comment: Spot on I understand it, because its alternating. Cool.